# Using Abstract Classes to Construct a Heap

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm a bit confused as to the actual implementation of code from abstract classes, and what its significance is.

I wrote code for a Max Heap, and I wanted to make an abstract class based on it so I could have a general outline for a heap that isn't just a "Max" heap.

The body of my MaxHeap looks like this:

```
public class MaxHeap {

    // A class for nodes, just has 3 fields, lchild, rchild, and value
    private HeapNode top;
    private List<HeapNode> heap;

    public MaxHeap() {
        this.top = null;
        this.heap = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //I won't go into the guts of these methods, but will explain

    //Displays the heap like [1,2,3,4,5,...]
    public void display() {...}

    //Adds a new HeapNode to the end of heap, if empty sets to top
    public void add(int value) {...}

    //Deletes a HeapNode at index pos
    public void delete(int pos) {...}

    //Swaps 2 Nodes within the heap
    protected void swap(int pos, int otherPos) {...}

    //// These are the methods that actually differ depending on the
    //// type of heap (maxheap, minheap, etc) so I would assume they
    //// would be abstract methods if writing an abstract class?
    |
    |
    V

    //Called within add method, heapifys the heap after adding a new Node
    protected void addHeapify(int pos) {...}

    //Called within delete method, heapifys the heap after deleted Node
    protected void deleteHeapify(int pos) {...}

    //Called within deleteHeapify for "if (pos==0) {...}", delete max Node
    protected deleteExtremum() {...}
}
```

My question reflects how exactly would I implement this on a more abstract level? I want to take my coding to the next level, and need to understand this. Would I make an abstract class like such?

```
public abstract class Heap {

private HeapNode top;
private List<HeapNode> heap;

public Heap() {...}

// **************
// public methods
// **************

public void display() {...}
public void add(int value) {...}
public void delete(int pos) {...}

// ******************
// non-public methods
// ******************

protected void swap(int pos, int otherPos) {...}

// ****************
// abstract methods
// ****************

protected abstract void addHeapify(int pos);
protected abstract void deleteHeapify(int pos);
protected abstract void deleteExtremum();

}
```

Understanding the correct way to "abstract-ify" the original class will greatly help me.

Is it correct to add the fields and constructor within the abstract class, and even though add, delete, swap, and display don't change across different heaps, should those methods be abstract as well?

I was also wondering if I should maybe use an interface instead, but it just seems like a more strict abstract class, and I won't be able to define add, delete, swap, and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract class is a generalization of several concrete classes. It is used to share the common functionality and data. As it is abstract, it can not be instantiated(used) without some customization. If the class can be used as is, it is not abstract.

Significant point if you need abstract class against interface is if the abstraction contains data. You can have abstract class with data fields and only abstract methods.

Abstract methods should be used when your generic functionality wants some inheritor-specific data or processing. Like if your `add` method needs to call `addHeapify` for some reason, but don't care which way it is implemented.

If you need all the descendents to have some method, but it is not used in common functionality, it is wise to use Interface, as Interface defines how class should behave, but doesn't define which data it contains. Thus you can have an abstraction of two classes containing different data. 
In Java 8 you can implement `default methods` right in the interface (it was not possible before), so you need abstract class only if you have common data to store in it.

Keep in mind that references to abstract classes or interfaces can be used by other algorithms to invoke yours without knowing what is the implementation behind the reference. This is mostly used to make code variable as you can substitute any implementation of the interface or abstract class without changing client code.